# Copy multiple files from multiple directories to one single directory

Tags: batch-file, file-io

I have to copy a large amount of files, that I have listed in an Excel spread sheet, from numerous directories. I had previously attempted to use this spread sheet to write a .BAT program to copy these files to one single directory to create a flat file. (Here is the funny newb part) It worked great until I realized there were duplicate files across the many directories I was coping from, and then I realized that the files with the same names would get overwritten with the next file with the same name in the next line of the program that was coming from a different directory. As it turns out that is sort of OK, however I need the result of the copy program to have the latest file and not just the "last in line" file that the program comes to.

How do I write a batch program that copies these files, listed in my Excel spread sheet, and only takes the latest files according to the time stamp in Windows and pastes them to a single directory?

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried please, will help in editing

Comment: It's not clear how you are using an Excel spreadsheet as a source file list. Could you post the existing batch script?